Intel server not booting with dual processors
I've bought an intel S2600WF server. At first, I put two Intel Xeon Gold 6148 processors into the server, but then it got stuck on the initialization screen after "Memory initialization complete. No errors" with POST code 21. I found that if I removed the second CPU, it booted just fine. I've tried adding two ram sticks in all available spots, but it hasn't helped.
I have checked that both CPUs have the same stepping. I have also had each CPU in the computer at once, so none of them are faulty from what I can tell.
I have set the BIOS settings to default with the jumper, removed the storage device.
Here are the specs:

Windows 2019 Server
2x Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB DDR4 2666 MHz
Xeon Gold 6148


Have you tested both sockets by themselves?

@Ramhound The system doesn't boot at all without a CPU installed in the the first CPU socket.

How confident are you in that both sockets are actually functional?

I went ahead and bought another server of the same model to rule out the sockets being faulty. The same thing happens with that server, so the sockets aren't the problem.

I assume the firmware of the motherboard is at its current release level?

Correct, it's the latest release available.
